# How can I change some image editor options using python?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

Let's say my UI looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do is to change some **Image Editor** `bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0].screen.areas[1]` options through my addon. For example, to change the image of Image Editor I do sometihng like this:

```
texture_name = "face.png"

area = bpy.context.window_manager.windows[0].screen.areas[1]
area.spaces.active.image = bpy.data.images[texture_name]
```

In case I want to change, let's say the header of Image Editor. If it will appear or not. Or the zoom ratio of the image. How I'll do that?

I found this `bpy.context.space_data.show_region_header = False` and this `bpy.ops.image.view_zoom_ratio(ratio=1.0)` using right click, but I don't know how to use it. Because for example if I use `bpy.context.space_data.show_region_header = False` from my addon, it will not hide Image Editor's header but 3D Viewport's header.

I also try to iterate through areas and do `bpy.context.space_data.show_region_header = False` and `bpy.ops.image.view_zoom_ratio(ratio=1.0)` from there. But I can't find the syntax. Because for example, `bpy.ops.image.view_zoom_ratio(ratio=1.0)` should be something like `area.spaces.view_zoom_ratio(ratio=1.0)`. Which doesn't work and gives me this error `AttributeError: 'bpy_prop_collection' object has no attribute 'view_zoom_ratio'`

So, any idea how can I do this?

Comment: I would really like to know why my question downvoted this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find Image Editor views from screen.areas with filtering and call view_zoom_ratio operator with [Overriding Context](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html?highlight=overriding%20context#overriding-context).

```
import bpy

override = bpy.context.copy()

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:

    #if area.type != 'IMAGE_EDITOR' or area.ui_type != 'VIEW': # Image Editor View only
    #if area.type != 'IMAGE_EDITOR' or area.ui_type != 'UV': # UV Editor View only
    if area.type != 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        continue

    area.spaces.active.show_region_header = False

    override['area'] = area
    bpy.ops.image.view_zoom_ratio(override, ratio=1.0)

    area.tag_redraw()
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your time!!! To make it work I had to replace `if area.type != 'IMAGE_EDITOR' or area.ui_type != 'VIEW':` with `if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':` and remove the `continue`. Would you like  to check it again and change it so to mark your answer as correct?

Comment: Note that I used `area.ui_type! ='VIEW'` to exclude the UV Editor View. So my script works only on the Image Editor View. Do you want a script that works in UV Editor View as well as Image Editor View?

Comment: One "subquestion"! In case I have three `image editors` opened and for example I want to point the second one?

Comment: You can make a new question.

Comment: I made it here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201893/how-can-i-loop-through-screen-areas-and-point-to-specific-area