# How can I loop through screen areas and point to specific area?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

To loop through screen areas and find `IMAGE_EDITOR` I do:

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR':
        # Do stuff
```

But what if I have three image editors opened and for example I want to point the second one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean the second one but you can select the second one with further conditional list:

```
[area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == 'IMAGE_EDITOR'][1]
```

And also there are properties `x` and `y` for area type, which indicate the bottom-left corner position in your screen. You can write some sorting function to select the desired one.

[Area(bpy_struct) — Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html)

Comment: the origin is the bottom-left corner.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time!!!

Comment: @tetii Indeed. thanks for the correction